# React-Table + Axios rendering error - data.forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-table

I see this is a fairly common question, sorry to ask it again but none of the answers to similar questions work for me. Using the very popular Axios / React-Tutorial, I'm able to pull and render info with this call -

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await axios("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=snow");
      setData(result.data);
    })();
  }, []);
```

If I switch it out for the API I'm trying to call, it looks like this -

```
      useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await axios('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myanimelist.net/v2/anime/30230?fields=id,title,genres',{
          headers: { 'X-MAL-CLIENT-ID' : 'THIS IS WHERE MY API KEY WOULD GO',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',},
          responseType: 'json'
                });
      setData(result.data);
    })();
  }, []);
```

As you can guess, running this gets me various shades of 'useTable.js:591 Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function'

If I console.log the various elements here I see objects coming down the pipes, similar to the tutorial example. Data looks identical in terms of how it's organized. But for whatever reason the rendering component just refuses to run.

I saw another solution hint the issue was the table rendering before the data is ready and suggested adding something like 'return !data.length ? (Loading..)' to the return clause, but when I do that the site just hangs indefinitely. No errors but nothing happens either. I'm working with two files, App.js and Table.js. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Posting full code below -

```
//App.js
import React, { useMemo, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Table from "./Table";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      axios
      .get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myanimelist.net/v2/anime/30230?fields=id,title,genres',{
          headers: { 'X-MAL-CLIENT-ID' : 'REDACTED',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',},
          responseType: 'json'
                })
      .then(result => setData(result.data))
  }, []);


  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        
          
            Header: "TITLE",
            accessor: "title"
          
        
      }
    ],
    []
  );

console.log(columns)
console.log(data)
console.log('this is property data ' +Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data))

  return  (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;



// Table.js

import React from "react";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

export default function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the useTable Hook to send the columns and data to build the table
  const {
    getTableProps, // table props from react-table
    getTableBodyProps, // table body props from react-table
    headerGroups, // headerGroups, if your table has groupings
    rows, // rows for the table based on the data passed
    prepareRow // Prepare the row (this function needs to be called for each row before getting the row props)
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  /* 
    Render the UI for your table
    - react-table doesn't have UI, it's headless. We just need to put the react-table props from the Hooks, and it will do its magic automatically
  */
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
 {// Loop over the table rows
       rows.map(row => {
         // Prepare the row for display
         prepareRow(row)
  return (
           <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
             {// Loop over the rows cells
             row.cells.map(cell => {
               // Apply the cell props
               return (
                 <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                   {// Render the cell contents
                   cell.render('Cell')}
                 </td>
               )
             })}
           </tr>
         )
       })}
     </tbody>
   </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have just tested your code but with **different** api url `URI of the service` and it is working all fine.
I have used [{JSON} Placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) the Free fake API for testing and prototyping.

You can always test your `API` with a third party tool such as [Postman](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basics-of-api-testing-using-postman/), this will allow you to test your `API` status before writing any code.

sanbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-water-tkid7s?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please make sure API data response is an valid array type

Comment: @Enfieldli apologies, could you clarify how to test that?

Comment: For learning purpose, please try a simpler api like the `{JSON} Placeholder` Omar Dieh mentioned above, it's free and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Issue was found to be react-table's trouble mapping a single object returned via the API - if a call returned an array of objects, code worked. Forcing a single object into a one object array seemed to resolve the initial issue, but presents other problems rendering.

Using the code above but simply switching out the API call

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await axios("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=snow");
      setData(result.data);
    })();
  }, []);
```

This call is set to return multiple results and works.

```
      useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await axios("https://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=girls");
      setData(result.data);
    })();
  }, []);
```

This call returns one result, and will lead to the issue described above. Not sure if a better solution would be to force single results into a one length set or tweak something on the react-table side.

Comment: Please add the code you are using, as this can help other people with similar issues, and you can also get some advice if it can be improved